# Mail-list implementation (database design)

Tags: database

I am currently refactoring a web-app. Right now there is a 'Contact' table that has a one-to-one correspondence with the main 'Client' table, with a bool indicating if clients want to receive mail. The mail-list is accessed about once per month, and the clients' profile page is accessed many times a day. I am thinking if it would be 'cleaner' to make a new table with the client ids of everyone in the mail-list, as querying if the key is in the table should take about the same time as accessing the information. Should I do that, or should I leave it as it is?

Thanks,
Joyce

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am actually ashamed to say that I forgot about this completely as other work is preventing me to even have time to think about refactoring this code. Part of the reason I was considering this was because there is a potential requirement for multiple emails with each user. But since this is not set in stone, I'll just leave it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An association table with (clientid, emailid) is too much normalized form. I think its better to keep like this. Also if you want to show contact emailid in any ui screen, you can avoid an inner join overhead due to this new association table.

However in future if you came across a requirement to have multiple emailids associated with a clientid, you could think about creating an association table then.

Answer (score 1):

Leave it as is. Why complicate? Keep it as simple as possible.